# alternative of map in java for better performance

Tags: java, selenium, testng

alternative of map in java for better performance

Comment: Please add log.  Are all methods in the same class?

Comment: Yes, all the methods are in same class.

Comment: @AbhinavSinghMaurya "Improved formatting" sounds like a joke ...

Comment: @Tom I believe its not a joke. I have added comments as asked while I edited and formatted the question.

Comment: are you running just `priority = 1` cases? priority is increased one by one.

Comment: @AbhinavSinghMaurya Ahh, during the "Help and improvement queue"? Please note that these "edit comments" are posted as a comment under the question, so it is better to explain what you've done, so OP knows what he did wrong. "Improved formatting" alone won't help him much. For example a link to the corresponding help page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting would be appropriate. Please don't take that "sounds like a joke" personally ;).

Comment: @Mesut i am running each test cases increasing priority by 1

Comment: Please post the log for someone to help you out ..nothing seems apparently wrong with the code